# Evaluation of self-defined functions

Tags: functions, function-construction

I defined a function that I call `disc` which I want to minimize later. The function is defined as

```
disc[dt_]:=Total[(Log[vDat] - Log[(x'[tDat -dt] /. nsol)])^2]
```

and it quantifies the discrepancy between measured data (the time series `{tDat,vDat}`) and the solution to a differential equation that was obtained with `NDSolve`.

My problem is that this function works great sometimes:

[image: graph]

but fails in other applications:

[image: Another graph]

I tried hard to get to the bottom of this, but I just can't understand what's wrong. Suggestions?

Clarification: `disc[1]` returns a number and not a `{number}`.

Comment: Change the definition of `disc[]`: `disc[dt_?NumericQ] := (* stuff *)`.

Comment: Thanks @J.M., but `Evaluated` is not a valid option for `FindMinimum` and  changing the definition does not work.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of something else, so I removed that section. Unfortunately, I don't think we can be more helpful unless you at least show us your `tDat`, `vDat`, and `nsol`...

Comment: @J.M. `tDat` and `vDat` are simply lists of real numbers. `nsol` is the result of `First[NDSolve[...]]`. I don't think there's a problem with them. 

Also, you see that applying `disc` to numbers one at a time (as I've shown with `disc[#]&/@` works like a charm. 

I suspect that it's something internal with the way `Plot` or `FindMinimum` evaluate functions rather than a problem with the data.

Comment: In that case, the following works nicely on my end: `BlockRandom[SeedRandom[45, Method -> "Legacy"]; tDat = RandomReal[5, 6]; vDat = RandomReal[5, 6];];
nsol = First[NDSolve[{x''[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, -8, 8}]]; disc[dt_?NumericQ] := 
 Total[(Log[vDat] - Log[(x'[tDat - dt] /. nsol)])^2]; FindMinimum[disc[t], {t, 0, 2}]`

Comment: A general remark is that defining functions which implicitly depend on global variables is, for most cases, a recipe for disaster. It may be also the case for your function. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for this remark. I know that, and my function is actually `disc[sol_,dt_]` and I have to give it the interpolating function too. I omitted that in the post for clarity.

Comment: Always try to post a running (and minimal) example of your problem. Otherwise you most probably will get right answers for the wrong problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the problem is that you use the same variable symbol for the function returned by `NDSolve` and for the functions `Plot` and `FindMinimum`.

Here is a simplified example I tried. This is just an example equation from the documentation:

```
nsol = First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] Cos[t + x[t]], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 30}]
```

Here is a minimal definition of `disc` that demonstrates the problem:

```
disc[dt_] := x'[dt] /. nsol
```

Using the variable `t` the functions `Plot` and `FindMinimum` work fine:
[image: screenshot1]
But using the variable `x` (the same name as the function solved for by `NDSolve`) I get similar problems to what you got:
[image]